# PHP Loop and change name variable

Tags: php

if for example I have something like this,

```
$url_1='........';
$url_2='........';
$url_3='........';
```

And I run a for loop with i going from 1 to 3, is it possible to change the variable name called in the fucntion basename, to go from url_1 to url_2 to url_3?

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    $file_name= basename($url.'_'.i);
    echo $file_name;
```

The above code doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, you can: `basename(${'url_' . $i});`. Note that your loop starts at zero, not one.

Comment: Use an array, I would suggest.

Comment: Wow! @KIKO Software that is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. And yes, I will fix that aswell now.

Comment: Also cahnge ($url.'_'.i); to ($url.'_'.$i);

Comment: I forgot to say that this is nothing magical, see: [Variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).